# Screen not reflecting changes to view model

Tags: android, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I have a screen with a view model. This screen has a composable whose job is to render UI content based on the view model. When the composable is clicked it navigates to a filter screen where a user can update the filters which is updated in a view model. See screenshot
[image: Filter screen]

When I navigate back, the parent screen still retains the old data prior to navigating to the filter settings in screenshot.

Parent composable contains a filter card composable whose data is driven by the view model. When clicked, it navigates to the Filter screen as shown in the image above.

```
@Composable
fun ParentScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    vm: FilterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

        Filters(
            showCompleted = vm.filterState.showCompleted,
            showCustomerReturns = vm.filterState.showCustomerReturns,
            vendorName = vm.filterState.vendorName,
            loadGroup = vm.filterState.loadGroup,
            onClick = { navController.navigate(NavGraph.FILTER_SCREEN) }
        )
}
```

The Filter View Model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FilterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val filter: Filter
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _filterState: MutableStateFlow<FilterState> by lazy {
      MutableStateFlow(
            FilterState(
                filter.loadGroup(),
                filter.showCompleted(),
                filter.showCustomerReturns(),
                filter.vendorName(),
            )
        )
    }
    var filterState = _filterState.asStateFlow()
}

data class FilterState(
    val loadGroup: String,
    val showCompleted: Boolean,
    val showCustomerReturns: Boolean,
    val vendorName: String,
)
```

Returning to the parent screen is done with `navController.popBackStack()`.

In the filter screen, each option in the screenshot is handled by a config view model. See below

```
@HiltViewModel
class ConfigFilterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val configFilter: ConfigFilter
): ViewModel() {
    private val _loadGroup = MutableStateFlow("")
    var loadGroup = _loadGroup.asStateFlow()

    private val _showCustomerReturns = MutableStateFlow(false)
    var showCustomerReturns = _showCustomerReturns.asStateFlow()

    private val _showCompleted = MutableStateFlow(false)
    var showCompleted = _showCompleted.asStateFlow()

    private val _vendorName = MutableStateFlow("")
    var vendorName = _vendorName.asStateFlow()

    init {
        _loadGroup.value = configFilter.loadGroup()
        _showCompleted.value = configFilter.showCompleted()
        _showCustomerReturns.value = configFilter.showCustomerReturns()
        _vendorName.value = configFilter.vendorName()
    }

    fun toggleShowCustomerReturns() {
        _showCustomerReturns.value = _showCustomerReturns.value.not()
        configFilter.toggleShowCustomerReturns()
    }

    fun toggleShowCompleted() {
        _showCompleted.value = _showCompleted.value.not()
        configFilter.toggleShowCompleted()
    }

    fun saveLoadGroup(text: String) {
        _loadGroup.value = text
        configFilter.saveLoadGroup(text)
    }

    fun saveVendorName(text: String) {
        _vendorName.value = text
        configFilter.saveVendorName(text)
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? The app uses Jetpack compose and Hilt for dependency injection.

Comment: Can you share the viewmodel code?

Comment: @froots I have included the view model code. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: can you share codes of filter screen "where a user can update the filters which is updated in a view model"

Comment: @Amani I have added the view model code that handles option click. There is no view for that. The newly add view model is a singleton available across the entire app. The parent screen reads this view model.

Comment: In `FilterViewModel`  you are using an object of type `Filter` for view to show but in `ConfigFilterViewModel` you are updating an object of type `ConfigFilter` how they are related to each other? To update views you must update `_filterState`. where you are updating `_filterState` in `FilterViewModel`?

Comment: I have two view models, one is used for the filter settings screen (pictured above), the other is used for the parent screen. The parent screen renders a card that can be clicked to go to the filter settings screen (pictured above). When changes are made in the filter settings screen, the other view model in the parent screen should get the updated state - that part is not working.

Comment: How the other viewmodel gets updated state? That part which is not working is your problem but you did not share its code here. If you want answer you must clearly explain how state are flowing in your code.

Comment: I already shared both view model code. The parent screen uses the filter view model, while the filter settings screen uses the config filter view model.

Answer (score 0):

You are not collecting your flow so you are not getting the new values.

In your ParentScreen Composable collect your filterFlow as a State and use it to pass the values.

```
@Composable
fun ParentScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    vm: FilterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    val filterState by vm.filterState.collectAsState()

    Filters(
        showCompleted = filterState.showCompleted,
        showCustomerReturns = filterState.showCustomerReturns,
        vendorName = filterState.vendorName,
        loadGroup = filterState.loadGroup,
        onClick = { navController.navigate(NavGraph.FILTER_SCREEN) }
    )
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but it does not work.

Comment: How do you update the values when you click on a button?

Comment: I have added the view model code that handles button click.

Answer (score 0):

To update `ParentScreen` you must call `_filterState.value = FilterState(/*arguments*/)`
in `FilterViewModel`. But i don't see it in your code?

Use this function to update `ParentScreen`:

```
fun updateState(loadGroup: String,
    showCompleted: Boolean,
    showCustomerReturns: Boolean,
    vendorName: String) {

       _filterState.value = FilterState(
                                 loadGroup,
                                 showCompleted,
                                 showCustomerReturns,
                                 vendorName
                            )
}
```